# Convert vertical data to horizontal in excel

Tags: excel

In an excel sheet I have data as below:

```
Name        Age
-------    -------
XYZ        24
ABC        25
CDE        26
GHI        27
```

I want this data to be converted as following in excel sheet.

```
Name1     Age1    Name2     Age2    Name3     Age3    Name4     Age4
XYZ       24      ABC       25      CDE       26      GHI       27
```

Is this possible? please help. Thanks!

Comment: I can if it does the trick? but I don't know how to use that.

Comment: Is it a one off or will you need to do this regularly?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of previous questions. Probably belongs on superuser. But how is it off topic?

Answer (score 4):

As for a Non-VBA solution - you can do this with some creative use of autofill and sort:

Do some creative autofill and sorting:
[image: AutoFillSort1]

Copy and Paste Transposed:
[image: AutoFillSort2]

And your done:
[image: AutoFillSort3]

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in your vba editor (standard module) and add the code to a button.
The code assumes the table to start from range "A1".
The first row contains the headers, the other rows the values as in your example.
I pasted the output as from row 8.
Let me know if it helped.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Name_Age()

Dim oRange                  As Excel.Range
Dim iRange_Cols             As Integer
Dim lRange_Rows             As Long
Dim lCnt                    As Long

Dim vArray                  As Variant
Dim vArray_Dest             As Variant

Dim lUbound_Rows            As Long
Dim lUBound_Cols            As Long


Set oRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange
iRange_Cols = oRange.Columns.Count
lRange_Rows = oRange.Rows.Count - 1
ReDim vArray(1 To lRange_Rows, 0 To iRange_Cols)
ReDim vArray_Dest(1 To iRange_Cols, 1 To (lRange_Rows * iRange_Cols))
vArray = oRange

lCnt = 0
For lCnt = 1 To lRange_Rows
    vArray_Dest(1, (lCnt * 2) - 1) = CStr("Name" & lCnt)
    vArray_Dest(1, (lCnt * 2)) = CStr("Age" & lCnt)
    vArray_Dest(2, (lCnt * 2) - 1) = vArray(1 + lCnt, 1)
    vArray_Dest(2, (lCnt * 2)) = vArray(1 + lCnt, 2)
Next lCnt

lUbound_Rows = UBound(vArray_Dest, 1)
lUBound_Cols = UBound(vArray_Dest, 2)

Set oRange = Nothing
Set oRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(8 + lUbound_Rows - 1, lUBound_Cols))
oRange = vArray_Dest

End Sub
```